# nginx conf on a odoo server does not work

Tags: nginx, dns, odoo

This is how the nginx conf looks like this(the 'xxxx' parts are all correct and the same):

```
server {

    listen 80;
        server_name xxxxx-xxxxx.de;
        return 301 $scheme://www.xxxx-xxxx.de$request_uri;
    }

    server {

    listen 80;
    server_name *.xxxxxx-xxxxxx.de;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/xxxxx.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/xxxxx.error.log;

    # increase proxy buffer to handle some Odoo web requests
    proxy_buffers              16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout      120s;
    proxy_send_timeout         600s;
    proxy_read_timeout         600s;

    # Specifies the maximum accepted body size of a client request,
    # as indicated by the request header Content-Length.
    client_max_body_size       100m;

    # force timeouts if the backend dies
    proxy_next_upstream        error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

    # by default, do not forward anything
    proxy_redirect             off;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
    }
}
```

When I open the site I get `connection refused`.

Nginx error log says: `conflicting server name "xxxxx-xxxxx.de" on 0.0.0.0:80`

Also I commented `# include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`;

And I deleted the default conf in sites-enabled.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was: "service nginx start"

I always just typed "nginx -t" + "service nginx reload" after I changed my config